# How to hide Google logo/splash before bootanimation AOSP

Tags: android, hide, splash-screen, android-source

I need to disable Google logo/splash
Anyone know solutions? (AOSP) API 29

|Bootloader| -> |Splash/Logo| -> |Linux kernel| -> |Android Native| -> |Bootanimation|